# render table row from array: react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I am trying to call a function to render table rows using the map function on an array of texts I receive as props but for some reason they are not being rendered. Am I making a syntactical mistake? I have verified that the license text props array is not empty and simply returns an array of strings.

```
const showLicenseText = () => {
 return licenseText.map(text => {
      <tr>
        <ThPadding>
          License Information
          {':'}
        </ThPadding>
        <td>{text}</td>
      </tr>
  })
}
```

The original code in render method is:

```
return (
  <table>
    <tbody>
      {bbbFileOpenDate && (
        <tr>
          <ThPadding>
            {text.bbbFileOpened}
            {':'}
          </ThPadding>
          <td>{bbbFileOpenDate}</td>
        </tr>
      )}
      {yearsInBusiness && !isOutOfBusiness && (
        <tr>
          <ThPadding>
            {yearsInBusinessLabel}
            {':'}
          </ThPadding>
          <td>{yearsInBusiness}</td>
        </tr>
      )}
      {businessStartDate && (
        <tr>
          <ThPadding>
            {businessStartDateLabel}
            {':'}
          </ThPadding>
          <td>{businessStartDate}</td>
        </tr>
      )}
      {showLicenseText}
      {locationStartDate && (
        <tr>
          <ThPadding>
            {locationStartDateLabel}
            {':'}
          </ThPadding>
          <td>{locationStartDate}</td>
        </tr>
      )} ....
```

Comment: maybe surround with `return ( <tr> etc..</tr> )` ?

Comment: nope does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `map` you need to `return` your row. The map expects something returned

```
const showLicenseText = () => {
 return licenseText.map(text => {
      return (<tr>
        <ThPadding>
          License Information
          {':'}
        </ThPadding>
        <td>{text}</td>
      </tr>)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to call it! and In the map since you are using `{}` you need explicit `return` statement

```
  {showLicenseText()}
```

Also I would modify a little like below:

define function outside of `render`

```
showLicenseText = (licenseTextRef) => {
 return licenseTextRef.map(text => {
      return <tr>
        <ThPadding>
          License Information
          {':'}
        </ThPadding>
        <td>{text}</td>
      </tr>
  })
}

==============================

  {this.showLicenseText(licenseText)}
```

Comment: @Ackman do you get any errors? Do you have `showLicenseText` defined in your `render()` function?

Comment: yes that might be the case. It is defined inside. should I move it out?

Comment: Did it and did not help. still nothing.

Comment: If you move it out then you would have to reference it with `this.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198677/discussion-between-rikin-and-ackman).

Comment: done. and I get a console error "you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it."